# Using list of serialized objects

Tags: java, android

I'm learning Android/Java programming, but I'm confused about persistant data.
After a lot of research it seems that the best way to store objects is to serialize them in a file, but I couldn't find a simple way to retrieve these objects.

If I create two objects and save their serialized versions, how can I retieve and list both of them? Do I need to create a file for each object with a specific ID in the filename so I can list them with a `getFilesDir`?

Comment: Glad to help.  If one of these questions solved your issue, please mark the accepted answer.  It lets others with the same issue find help faster, and lets us know we helped you.

Answer (score 3):

Depends on how complex those objects are (your personal preferences I guess), I have used `SharedPreferences` to store simple objects before, just for the sake of simplicity, while a co-worker makes generous use of SQLite, but that suits his needs.

Since you do not state what is being stored, the best advice I can give you right now is have read [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html), it covers how persistent data should be dealt with on Android.

Comment: +1 that's the right place to start working your way to a solution

Answer (score 0):

"best" way?  Please define your criteria.

There are databases (relational and non-relational) or file systems.  You can serialize lots of ways: Java serialization, XML, Google's protobuf, and others.

Yes, you'll need a way to specify a unique representation with its object.  In a relational database, you'd use a primary key.  You need something like that in any system you use.

If you serialize via some mechanism to a file system, you'll have to write the object into the desired format and stream it to a file.  To go the other way, specify the key for the object, read the serialized data, and parse it back into the object.

Comment: Best way because serialization store the entire object. If I add or remove a component in the object in the future I don't need to care storing this component. however, i've taken a look into different open source projects and the SharedPreferences seems the good way for my needs.